# ViewController unwanted allocation and initialised

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having some trouble understanding why my viewController gets allocated a second time.
the overall idea is this:

1) i have a first viewController (called loginScreenViewController) in this viewController the user selects login from FB/T/Mail

2)once the user selects the mail option i push the next viewController called mailRegistrationViewController

3)once the user logs/reg with this viewController i segue to the next viewController called homeViewController and pop the mailRegistrationViewController of the navigation stack

pop

```
NSMutableArray *navStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navStack removeObjectIdenticalTo:self];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:navStack];
```

navigation stack after removing mailRegistration:

> ```
> "<SELoginScreenViewController: 0x8f46030>",
> "<SEHomeViewController: 0x8e62dc0>"
> ```

4) in the homeViewController once the user logs out, i log him out and pop the homeViewController, this time with

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // remove from the navigation stack
```

once again i print the navigation stack before and after the removing

before:

> ```
> "<SELoginScreenViewController: 0x8f46030>",
> "<SEHomeViewController: 0x8e62dc0>"
> ```

after:

> ```
> "<SELoginScreenViewController: 0x8f46030>"
> ```

Then in the loginViewController in viewWillAppear i log the navigation stack and this is what i get:

> ```
> "<SELoginScreenViewController: 0x8f46030>",
> "<SELoginScreenViewController: 0x8f6ea70>"
> ```

My login view gets allocated and initialised once more.
If any has an idea about why this is happening, or if i need to add more code please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to alter the UINavigationController's ViewController stack artificially. You should use the `popViewController:animated` and `pushViewController:animated` methods exclusively for altering the VC stack.

Comment: Why not put a breakpoint in the initialiser of `SELoginScreenViewController` and find out when the second instance is getting created...

Comment: @VinodVishwanath can you elaborate more about when should i use it? and do you have a better way to remove the viewController from the stack?

Comment: @MikePollard if i put a breakpoint in the init ill just know that the method is getting called not why it's getting called. thanks

Comment: You should see a stack trace that'll indicate why

Comment: I think the problem come form the fact that loginViewController is the root view, so if i pop to the root view it gets allocated again

Comment: @YuviGr,
I have posted a new answer with the approach I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should only use `pushViewController:animated` and `popViewController:animated` to alter the viewController stack of a UINavigationController.

Perform step 3 like this:

```
    do
    {
    id *poppedVC = [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 
            // animation not required since you will soon push a new view controller with animated:YES

    } while(poppedVC != self);


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];
```

Basically this changes the order in which you remove the mailRegistrationViewController from your viewController stack.

Comment: Hey that work! Thanks! I gusse i made a bad alteration to the navigation controller stack

Comment: You're welcome. You can also do this in just two lines of code by first calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` and then `[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeViewController animated:YES];`, if you are sure that your mailRegistrationViewController will always be the top view controller of the stack.